# Hydrogen Ions — Common, right?

Tags: definitions

The Wikipedia entry for Ion states "A positively charged hydrogen ion (or proton) can readily combine with other particles and therefore is only seen isolated when it is in a gaseous state or a nearly particle-free space."  Cells pumping ions across membranes is very common so can someone help me understand what context might be implied by the quote?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*what context might be implied by the quote*". What specifically are you asking about?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This appears to be a chemistry question and is almost certainly answered on [Chemistry.SE]. The short answer is that aqueous H+ is actually H3O+. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Note in particular the section on ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what specifically you're asking about, but I have a guess. It is true that positively-charged hydrogen ions, or bare protons, are typically only observed in gaseous/plasma states and hard vacuums, and it is also true that cells routinely pump positively-charged hydrogen ions across membranes. This is not a paradox because in aqueous solutions, hydrogen ions exist as $H_3O^+$, also known as [hydronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydronium) or hydroxonium.

[image: Hydronium]

<sup>Image from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hydroxonium-cation.svg)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track with your thinking about the paradox of an actual proton being pumped across the membrane, and it's just a problem of how the chemistry is communicated. The protons actually move along what is called the proton channel, which essentially is a row of protonated amino acids like glutamate (glutamic acid) or histidine.

If we think about complex 1 in mitochondria (below), when a proton in the matrix is "pumped" across, it actually "pushes" protons down the proton channel into the matrix (See the light blue line in the figure below). Think of a series of train cars on a track getting pushed.

Finding these proton channels and figuring out how they work is actually a very competitive field. Since they are buried in the membrane, they are challenging to work with, and we don't know much about them.

[image]

Even as someone who works in the field, I have to remind myself that all chemistry works this way. If it is water, protons, or electrons, talking about a single molecule is the wrong way of thinking about it.

Citation for Figure https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-17957-0

Comment: "talking about a single molecule is the wrong way of thinking about it" super helpful